# Given $m,n \notin U$, could $m + n \in U$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If both elements are not in the linear subspace $U$, could their sum be in it?

Comment: Sure. For example one could be the negative of the other. Now you should give a concrete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, consider $V=k^2$ as a $k$-vector space for a field $k$ and consider the subspace $k \times \{0\}$. Then $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$ are not in that subspace but their sum is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the simplest example is $U=0$. Just take $v\in V$, $v\ne0$ and consider $m=v, n=-v$.